# how to do one by one animation on svg path object?

Tags: svg, svg-animate, jquery-svg

i am v fresh user for svg object image. And i would like to do path animation one by one when mouse over on svg image. When mouse leave on object image the animation will reverse to the starting position. My svg object is like below: thank you!

```
<html><head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400" 
rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>



<div class="half yellow">
<div class="container">


<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" 
width="117.96px" height="117.96px" viewBox="0 0 117.96 117.96" enable- 
background="new 0 0 220 75" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="none" stroke="#ff9100" stroke-width="1" class="cls-1" d="M113.74,55.14a.58.58,0,0,1-.41-.17L85,26.62a.58.58,0,1,1,.82-.82l28.34,28.34a.58.58,0,0,1-.41,1Z" transform="translate(-11.62 -10.6)"></path>
<path fill="none" stroke="#ff9100" stroke-width="1" class="cls-1" d="M83.31,24.71a.58.58,0,0,1-.41-.17l-1-1a.58.58,0,1,1,.82-.82l1,1a.58.58,0,0,1-.41,1Z" transform="translate(-11.62 -10.6)"></path>
<path fill="none" stroke="#ff9100" stroke-width="1" class="cls-1" d="M41.89,99.61a.58.58,0,0,1-.41-.17L11.62,69.58l59-59L80.74,20.74a.58.58,0,0,1-.82.82L70.6,12.24,13.27,69.58l29,29a.58.58,0,0,1-.41,1Z" transform="translate(-11.62 -10.6)"></path>
<path fill="none" stroke="#ff9100" stroke-width="1" class="cls-1" d="M99.31,99.61a.58.58,0,0,1-.41-1l29-29-13-13a.58.58,0,1,1,.82-.82l13.77,13.77L99.72,99.44A.58.58,0,0,1,99.31,99.61Z" transform="translate(-11.62 -10.6)"></path>
<path fill="none" stroke="#ff9100" stroke-width="1" class="cls-1" d="M70.6,128.56,55.84,113.8a.58.58,0,0,1,.82-.82L70.6,126.91,84.54,113a.58.58,0,0,1,.82.82Z" transform="translate(-11.62 -10.6)"></path>
<path fill="none" stroke="#ff9100" stroke-width="1" class="cls-1" d="M111.66,111.25H29.54a.58.58,0,0,1,0-1.16h82.12a.58.58,0,1,1,0,1.16Z" transform="translate(-11.62 -10.6)"></path>
<path fill="none" stroke="#ff9100" stroke-width="1" class="cls-1" d="M99.31,99.61a.58.58,0,0,1-.58-.58V69.52L70.6,48.24,42.48,69.52V99a.58.58,0,0,1-1.16,0V68.94L70.6,46.78,99.89,68.94V99A.58.58,0,0,1,99.31,99.61Z" transform="translate(-11.62 -10.6)"></path>
<path fill="none" stroke="#ff9100" stroke-width="1" class="cls-1" d="M107,71.6a.58.58,0,0,1-.35-.12L70.6,44.19,47.15,61.94a.58.58,0,0,1-.7-.93L70.6,42.73l36.76,27.82a.58.58,0,0,1-.35,1Z" transform="translate(-11.62 -10.6)"></path>
<path fill="none" stroke="#ff9100" stroke-width="1" class="cls-1" d="M59.61,111.25a.58.58,0,0,1-.58-.58V88.57a11.58,11.58,0,1,1,23.16,0v4.74a.58.58,0,0,1-1.16,0V88.57a10.41,10.41,0,0,0-20.83,0v22.1A.58.58,0,0,1,59.61,111.25Z" transform="translate(-11.62 -10.6)"></path>
<path fill="none" stroke="#ff9100" stroke-width="1" class="cls-1" d="M99.27,114H85a.58.58,0,1,1,0-1.16H99.27a.58.58,0,0,1,0,1.16Z" transform="translate(-11.62 -10.6)"></path>
<path fill="none" stroke="#ff9100" stroke-width="1" class="cls-1" d="M56.25,114H42a.58.58,0,0,1,0-1.16H56.25a.58.58,0,1,1,0,1.16Z" transform="translate(-11.62 -10.6)"></path>
<path fill="none" stroke="#ff9100" stroke-width="1" class="cls-1" d="M99.31,65.77a.58.58,0,0,1-.58-.58v-15H90.56v3.62a.58.58,0,0,1-1.16,0V49H99.89V65.19A.58.58,0,0,1,99.31,65.77Z" transform="translate(-11.62 -10.6)"></path>
<path fill="none" stroke="#ff9100" stroke-width="1" class="cls-1" d="M34.19,71.6a.58.58,0,0,1-.35-1l10.54-8a.58.58,0,0,1,.7.93l-10.54,8A.58.58,0,0,1,34.19,71.6Z" transform="translate(-11.62 -10.6)"></path>
<line fill="none" stroke="#ff9100" stroke-width="1" class="cls-1" x1="69.98" y1="91.8" x2="69.98" y2="100.07"></line>
<path fill="none" stroke="#ff9100" stroke-width="1" class="cls-1" d="M81.6,111.25a.58.58,0,0,1-.58-.58V102.4a.58.58,0,0,1,1.16,0v8.27A.58.58,0,0,1,81.6,111.25Z" transform="translate(-11.62 -10.6)"></path>
<line fill="none" stroke="#ff9100" stroke-width="1" class="cls-1" x1="69.98" y1="86.07" x2="69.98" y2="88.57"></line>
<path fill="none" stroke="#ff9100" stroke-width="1" class="cls-1" d="M81.6,99.75a.58.58,0,0,1-.58-.58V96.67a.58.58,0,1,1,1.16,0v2.49A.58.58,0,0,1,81.6,99.75Z" transform="translate(-11.62 -10.6)"></path>
<path fill="none" stroke="#ff9100" stroke-width="0"  class="cls-1" d="M41.89,99.61a.58.58,0,0,1-.41-.17L11.62,69.58l59-59L80.74,20.74a.58.58,0,0,1-.82.82L70.6,12.24,13.27,69.58l29,29a.58.58,0,0,1-.41,1Z" ></path>
<path fill="none" stroke="#ff9100" stroke-width="0.3" class="cls-1" d="M99.31,99.61a.58.58,0,0,1-.41-1l29-29-13-13a.58.58,0,1,1,.82-.82l13.77,13.77L99.72,99.44A.58.58,0,0,1,99.31,99.61Z" transform="translate(-11.62 -10.6)"></path>
<path fill="none" stroke="#ff9100" stroke-width="1" class="cls-1" d="M70.6,128.56,55.84,113.8a.58.58,0,0,1,.82-.82L70.6,126.91,84.54,113a.58.58,0,0,1,.82.82Z" transform="translate(-11.62 -10.6)"></path>
</svg></div>
</div>

<div class="half grey"></div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: I would like to help. Unfortunately you have lots of **repeated paths**. Maybe you should go back to Illustrator (or whatever editor you are using) and remove the extra paths. Also, wile reediting please make sure to put your paths in the order you want them to be drawn.

Comment: thank you so much @enxaneta i'll update the file and will let you know :) thank you :)

Comment: Hi @enxaneta Please use https://jsfiddle.net/grkdzqb4/ as my new svg object.  Now only 2 paths in the object. I would like to do animate only for "cls-1a" class path. Initial load i can see "cls-1" path and mouse over it animation start run based on "cls-1a"path and mouse leave reverse back to the starting position. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all a few comments:

1. You may want to read first about [How SVG Line Animation Works](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/)
2. I couldn't use your second jsfiddle since those are very complex paths not suitable for paths animation. I decided to draw my own path.
3. The path I'm animating is `#myPath`. To build the `stroke-dasharray` for `#myPath` I use the paths in the `<defs>`. Please read the comments in the javascript.
4. I'm animating the path using CSS transition for the `stroke-dasharray` attribute.

```js
// the array of the lengths of the myPathGroup paths 
let lengths = [];
// the myPathGroup paths array
let paths = Array.from(myPathGroup.querySelectorAll("#myPathGroup path"));
// build the lengths array
paths.map((p) =>{lengths.push(p.getTotalLength())})
// total length of myPath
let l = myPath.getTotalLength();
// save the total length of myPath in a CSS variable
myPath.style.setProperty("--foo", l);
// build the stroke-dasharray for myPath
myPath.style.strokeDasharray = `${lengths.join(" ")} ${l} `;
```

```css
svg{max-height:100vh;}
path{
fill:none; 
stroke:black;
stroke-linecap: round;
stroke-linejoin:round;
}


#myPath{stroke:red; stroke-width:1.5px;  
  stroke-dashoffset:calc(var(--foo) * 1px);
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s;
}

svg:hover #myPath{stroke-dashoffset:0}

#myPathGroup path{stroke:green}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="318.293 -0.723 91.346 91.43">
<defs>
<g id="myPathGroup"> 
  <desc>Used to build the stroke-dasharray for myPath</desc>
  <path d="M363.966,0.712 L370.945,7.699" />
  <path d="M370.945,7.699 L372.72,9.475" display="none" />
  <path d="M372.72,9.475 L373.78,10.538" />
  <path d="M373.78,10.538 L375.381,12.139" display="none" />
  <path d="M375.381,12.139 L396.689,33.47" /> 
  <path d="M396.689,33.47 L398.054,34.836" display="none" />
  <path d="M398.054,34.836 L408.202,44.992 L385.924,67.324" />
  <path d="M385.924,67.324 L374.755,78.521" display="none" />
  <path d="M374.755,78.521 L364.008,89.293 L353.119,78.426" /> 
  <path d="M353.119,78.426 L341.877,67.205" display="none" />
  <path d="M341.877,67.205 L319.62,44.992 L363.966,0.712" />
  </g>
</defs>
<g id="yourPaths">
 <path d="M395.328,76.793h-62.656c-0.244,0-0.442-0.198-0.442-0.442
  c0-0.245,0.198-0.442,0.442-0.442h62.656c0.244,0,0.441,0.197,0.441,0.442C395.77,76.595,395.572,76.793,395.328,76.793
  L395.328,76.793z"/>
 <path d="M385.904,67.912c-0.244,0-0.441-0.198-0.441-0.442l0,0V44.954
  L364,28.718l-21.455,16.236v22.493c0,0.244-0.198,0.441-0.443,0.441c-0.244,0-0.442-0.197-0.442-0.441V44.512L364,27.604
  l22.348,16.907v22.936c0.012,0.243-0.176,0.451-0.42,0.465C385.92,67.912,385.912,67.912,385.904,67.912z"/>
 <path d="M391.771,46.541c-0.096,0-0.189-0.033-0.267-0.092L364,25.628
  l-17.892,13.543c-0.196,0.147-0.475,0.108-0.622-0.088c-0.147-0.196-0.108-0.474,0.088-0.622l0,0L364,24.514l28.047,21.226
  c0.178,0.168,0.186,0.447,0.018,0.625c-0.074,0.08-0.176,0.129-0.285,0.138L391.771,46.541z"/>
 <path  d="M355.615,76.793c-0.244,0-0.442-0.198-0.442-0.442l0,0V59.488
  c0-4.879,3.956-8.834,8.835-8.834c4.879,0,8.835,3.955,8.835,8.834v3.617c0,0.244-0.198,0.442-0.442,0.442
  s-0.442-0.198-0.442-0.442v-3.617c0-4.389-3.558-7.945-7.947-7.945c-4.388,0-7.946,3.557-7.946,7.945v16.862
  c0,0.244-0.198,0.442-0.442,0.442C355.62,76.793,355.618,76.793,355.615,76.793z"/>
 <path d="M385.875,78.891h-10.889c-0.244,0-0.441-0.197-0.441-0.441
  c0-0.245,0.197-0.443,0.441-0.443h10.889c0.244,0,0.441,0.198,0.441,0.443C386.316,78.693,386.119,78.891,385.875,78.891z"/>
 <path d="M353.051,78.891h-10.872c-0.245,0-0.443-0.197-0.443-0.441
  c0-0.245,0.198-0.443,0.443-0.443h10.872c0.245,0,0.443,0.198,0.443,0.443C353.494,78.693,353.296,78.891,353.051,78.891z"/>
 <path  d="M385.904,42.093c-0.244,0-0.441-0.198-0.441-0.443l0,0V30.206h-6.234v2.762
  c0,0.245-0.197,0.443-0.442,0.443c-0.244,0-0.442-0.198-0.442-0.443v-3.67h8.004V41.65
  C386.348,41.895,386.149,42.093,385.904,42.093z"/>
 <path d="M336.22,46.541c-0.244-0.02-0.425-0.234-0.404-0.478
  c0.009-0.108,0.058-0.21,0.137-0.285l8.042-6.104c0.196-0.147,0.474-0.108,0.622,0.088s0.108,0.474-0.088,0.622l0,0l-8.042,6.104
  C336.406,46.533,336.312,46.552,336.22,46.541z"/>
 <line x1="372.393" y1="70.041" x2="372.393" y2="76.351"/>
 <path  d="M372.393,76.793c-0.244,0-0.442-0.198-0.442-0.442l0,0v-6.31
  c0-0.244,0.198-0.443,0.442-0.443s0.442,0.199,0.442,0.443v6.31C372.835,76.595,372.637,76.793,372.393,76.793L372.393,76.793z"/>
 <line  x1="372.393" y1="65.669" x2="372.393" y2="67.576"/>
 <path  d="M372.393,68.019c-0.244,0-0.442-0.198-0.442-0.442l0,0v-1.907
  c0-0.245,0.198-0.442,0.442-0.442s0.442,0.197,0.442,0.442v1.899c0.005,0.244-0.19,0.446-0.435,0.45
  C372.398,68.019,372.395,68.019,372.393,68.019z"/>
</g>
  
<path id="myPath" d="M363.966,0.712 408.202,44.992 364.008,89.293 319.62,44.992z"  />


</svg>
```

Comment: Hi @enxaneta, Thank you so much. That is exactly what i want. Sure i'll read through the link that you shared. May i know when you draw the path you used illustrator or draw via code?

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer. I draw the paths from the `<defs>` in illustrator since I wanted to get the same result as in your drawing. I draw  `#myPath`  via code by taking the values from the `<defs>` paths.